# difference between object mode and nopython mode

Tags: python, python-2.7, numba

Numba offers compilation in two modes - nopython and object . Nopython mode is the faster one with certain limitations and it does not accesses python C API while the object mode does. What exactly is the difference between both the modes and why is nopython mode faster ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/glossary.html#term-nopython-mode)?

Comment: Yes.What is the advantage of using nopython mode or object mode ?

Comment: The object mode is a fallback for the nopython mode. If a function can compile in nopython mode it will do this even if you don't declare the nopython mode explicitly. The advantage of the nopython mode (from a user's point of view) is that it is an easy way to detect inefficiencies. Actually the difference of the object mode and the nopython mode is quite the same as running a function in the Python interpreter or calling a compiled function with the same functionality written eg. in C.